# Ansible Vmware добавить локального пользователя в группу Esxi Хоста

Tags: ansible

Для добавления локального пользователя на Esxi хост используется:

```
---
- name: create local user
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: create a user
      vmware_local_user_manager:
        hostname: host_name
        local_user_name: user_name
        local_user_password: user_pass
        username: root
        password: root_pass
        validate_certs: no
```

Каким образом средствами Ansible добавить этого пользователя в группу Administrator?

vmware_local_role_manager - если я правильно понял используется для добавления роли на хост.

vmware_object_role_permission - для назначения конкретных прав на различные объекты хоста.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения через использование vmware_object_role_permission.

```
---
- name: Add local user to group Administrator
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Assig user to group Administrator
      vmware_object_role_permission:
        role: Admin
        principal: user_name
        object_name: rootFolder
        state: present
        hostname: host_name
        username: root
        password: root_pass
        validate_certs: no
```